# Ionic 2 Web Audio Api

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm building an ionic 2 application that uses the users microphone.  On the web I would use the following to access the microphone.

```
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator['getUserMedia'] ||
    navigator['webkitGetUserMedia'] || navigator['mozGetUserMedia'] ||
    navigator['msGetUserMedia']);

(<any>navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true}).then((stream)=>{...........
```

When I ionic serve the application, the audio input is recorded and everything works.  However, when I run the app on a real android device, nothing happens when I make sound.  How can I access the users microphone in an Ionic 2 Application?

Comment: Do you have "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" as a permission?

Comment: I added the permission in platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try usin the cordova plugin to access the device microphone,check [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture/)